# Django changed form field detection

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm working with Django formset and I receiving new form data every time a (any) field has been changed by the user.
So my empty form.data looks like this:

```
MultiValueDict: {}
```

And after user changes any field my form.data becomes like this (I changed country field in the first form):

```
QueryDict: {
    'form-0-country': ['1'],
    'form-0-region': [''],
    'form-1-country': [''],
    'form-1-region': [''],
    'form-2-country': [''],
    'form-2-region': [''],
}
```

Here's my form if needed:

```
class SignCreateForm(ModelForm):
    data_url = '/sign-form-data/'

    class Meta:
        model = FormModel
        fields = ['country', 'region']

    class Media:
        # ajax form refreshing script
        js = ('js/formset.js',)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if self.is_bound:
            print(self.data)
```

And I need to **detect field that has been changed** by user on web page.
So I want to compare my previous form data with new received data but I'm not sure if it's a good idea because I don't have original data QueryDict with filled keys and empty values.

**Is there any way to get/calculate the modified form field?**

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand correctly but sounds like you could benefit from ajax.  Send the data to your view via ajax and evaluate it there.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, but I would like to find a way to calculate this using Django or at least find out if this is possible